# Generate HTML code with jsp or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

My problem is that I am trying to generate some HTML code to fit on this one GIANT form. This webapp will have 12 letters with 10 textboxes for each day of the week. I want some help having this generating HTML code for each day of the week. Instead of having to hard code each letter for each day of the week. Would love some help.

I think i might be headed in the right way if I use `window.onload = function()` but I am not sure how to use Javascript to generate a line in HTML when loading a window.

TLDR; how can I get either jsp or JS to copy paste this HTML into a webpage 12 times for each day of the week with unique ID's and Names.

```
<form>
   <div id="sectionpart">
        <%--Monday #1
        --%>
        <h2>Monday Mail Piece #1</h2>
        <div id ="formpart" >
            <table border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3">
                    <tr>
                        <td>A. FORM*: </td>
                        <td><input onblur="undo(this.id);"onfocus="highlight(this.id);" name="FORM_M1" type="number" maxlength="1" id="FORM_M1" value="8" size="10" required/></td>
                    </tr>               
                    <tr>
                        <td>B. ADDRESSEE*: </td>
                        <td><input onblur="undo(this.id);"onfocus="highlight(this.id);" type="number" name="ADDRESSEE_M1" id="ADDRESSEE_M1" value="8" size="10" maxlength="1" required/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>other field: </td>
                        <td><input onblur="undo(this.id);"onfocus="highlight(this.id);" type="text" name="otherdB_M1" id="otherB_M1" value="banana" size="30" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>C. RETURN ENVELOPE*: </td>
                        <td><input onblur="undo(this.id);"onfocus="highlight(this.id);" type="number" name="RETURN_ENVELOPE_M1" id="RETURN_ENVELOPE_M1" value="3" size="10" maxlength="1" required/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>D. SENDER TYPE*: </td>
                        <td><input onblur="undo(this.id);"onfocus="highlight(this.id);" type="number" name="SENDER_TYPE_M1" id="SENDER_TYPE_M1" value="10" size="10" maxlength="2" required/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>other field: </td>
                        <td><input onblur="undo(this.id);"onfocus="highlight(this.id);" type="text" name="otherD_M1" id="otherD_M1" value="" size="50" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>E. PURPOSE*: </td>
                        <td><input onblur="undo(this.id);"onfocus="highlight(this.id);" type="number" name="PURPOSE_M1" id="PURPOSE_M1" value="10" size="10" maxlength="2" required/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>other field: </td>
                        <td><input onblur="undo(this.id);"onfocus="highlight(this.id);" type="text" name="otherE_M1" id="otherE_M1" value="" size="50" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>F. ADVERTISING*: </td>
                        <td><input onblur="undo(this.id);"onfocus="highlight(this.id);" type="number" name="ADVERTISING_M1" id="ADVERTISING_M1" value="1" size="10" maxlength="1" required/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>G. READING: </td>
                        <td><input onblur="undo(this.id);"onfocus="highlight(this.id);" type="number" name="READING_M1" id="READING_M1" value="1" size="10" maxlength="1" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>H. REACTION: </td>
                        <td><input onblur="undo(this.id);"onfocus="highlight(this.id);" type="number" name="REACTION_M1" ID="REACTION_M1" value="1" size="10" maxlength="1" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>I. RESPONSE: </td>
                        <td><input onblur="undo(this.id);"onfocus="highlight(this.id);" type="number" name="RESPONSE_M1" ID="RESPONSE_M1" value="1" size="10" maxlength="1" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Class: 01020304 </td>
                        <td><input onblur="undo(this.id);"onfocus="highlight(this.id);" type="number" name="Classnums_M1" ID="Classnums_M1" value="01020304" size="10" maxlength="8" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>J. CLASS*: (OK to pick more than one)</td>
                        <td><ol type="1" >
                                <li><input type="checkbox" name="Presorted-PRSRT-FP" value="ON" />Presorted First-Class <b>or</b> PRSRT, <b>or</b> FP</li>
                                <li><input type="checkbox" name="FirstC-Postage" value="ON" />First-Class Postage</li>
                                <li><input type="checkbox" name="ForeverStamp" value="ON" />Forever Stamp</li>
                                <li><input type="checkbox" name="AUTO" value="ON" />AUTO</li>
                                <li><input type="checkbox" name="ABAFMBAV" value="ON" />AB, <b>or</b> AF, <b>or</b> MB, <b>or</b> AV</li>
                                <li><input type="checkbox" name="SinglePiece" value="ON" />Single Piece, <b>or</b> SNGLP, <b>or</b> SP</li>
                                <li><input type="checkbox" name="OutsideUS" value="ON" />Mail from outside the U.S.</li>
                                <li><input type="checkbox" name="FRANKED" value="ON" />Federal Government with Official Signature(FRANKED)</li>
                                <li><input type="checkbox" name="OtherFed" value="ON" />Other Federal Government Mail</li>
                                <li><input type="checkbox" name="OtherClassification" value="ON" />Other classification (Specify on Answer Booklet page 4)
                                    <input onblur="undo(this.id);"onfocus="highlight(this.id);" type="text" name="otherJ_M1" ID="otherJ_M1"value="" size="50" maxlength="50"/></li>
                            </ol>
                        </td>  
                    </tr>
            </table>
    </div>
    <div id="imagepart">
        <img src="img/MailAustin.JPG" width="100%" height="675px" alt="MailAustin" ID="IMAGE_M1"/>
    </div>
    </div>

     repeat
     repeat
     ......
     repeat

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pure JS to grab a set of html tags, clone them, and then attach them to the DOM. You could execute something like this in your onload function:

```
var form = document.querySelector('#form');
var inject = doucment.querySelector('#injection-point');
for ( var i = 0; i < 7; i++ ) {
  var cln = form.cloneNode(true);
  cln.setAttribute('id', 'form-' + i);
  inject.appendChild(cln);
}
```

Clone Node...
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_clonenode.asp

Also, if you have the freedom to use a framework, Polymer JS provides some excellent tools for repeating html without the need to write additional JS.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. Wouldn't this type and copy what's inside of a form? Hibernate is the framework that will be using to get data out of a SQL DB.

Comment: Yes, it makes a copy of the element along with all of its children, children's children, etc...

Comment: would there be a way that I could copy the "sectionpart" then clone it in the form? also advanced question... could i then  inject the textboxes with data i pull from a DB with the JS?. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are wanting to do in your first question. For your second question, if you are wanting to adjust the default value of an input, after you select the input element you can use JS to set the attribute => `input.setAttribute('value', 'text from DB here')`.